# HttpListener doesn't get a connection from Android devices(and probably other remote cons)

Tags: c#, android, network-programming, windows-phone-8.1, httplistener

Again, I need invaluable help of you.

I have project set up using HttpListener class to bind and listen on all found IPs and port(in this example) 1337.
Now, local connections(from my own computer typing IP:Port into address bar from browser) work just fine, but any connection from remote devices, even in the same wifi network, just don't hit listener.

Example code(instead of all found IPs I listen to all connections at port 1337)

```
HttpListener httplistener = new HttpListener();
httplistener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:80/");
httplistener.Start();
HttpListenerContext ctx = httplistener.GetContext();
Console.WriteLine("got context");
ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello"), 0, 5);
Console.WriteLine("response written");
ctx.Response.Close();
Console.WriteLine("response closed");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Well, from any browser I get response as it should be(and under normal circumstances I use it I get JSON object for my JS app), but from any device in wifi network I got timeout and I never got even to the context.

TcpListener on the other hand works properly. Why? I know the difference more or less and in TcpListener I can get a raw connection(like from Putty):

```
TcpListener tcplistener = new TcpListener(endpoint);
tcplistener.Start();
TcpClient tcpclient = tcplistener.AcceptTcpClient();
int dataAvailable = tcpclient.Available;
Console.WriteLine("connection accepted");
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tcpclient.GetStream()))
{
    sw.WriteLine("<html><body>hello</body></html>");
}
Console.WriteLine("response written");

tcpclient.Close();
Console.WriteLine("waiting for next connection");
```

Is it possible to somehow use HttpListener anyway or route connections to it? I really need possibility to connect to my app from every device through a html page. For any advices thank you. Tag #windows-phone-8.1 added because tried to connect from that device to HttpListener too with no positive effect.

Comment: It is unclear where the server is running? Is it on your PC, on Android device, on emulated android?

Comment: Did you open up port 80 on your firewall? If not, it could explain, why, from the machine itself via your browser you get access, but not from other devices...

Comment: @Übercoder: every port I'm using I'm opening. More - using portable HTTP server like Zervit is working just fine for serving purposes. On every port I open it of course.

Comment: rather a silly question: but the error couldn't be due to the fact, that you listen on `http://+:80/` instead of `http://*:80`, could it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, case closed. After exhausting every possible option, sniffing packets revealed that send packets are lost in translation and never get to my computer where server is started. I pushed on IT and they declined everything but after confronting with hard evidence they had to yield and admit that someone made this specific subnetwork work in a way that separates every client from each other.

So, when I manually opened a socket I was able to connect(and sometimes not, but I thought it was just my wrong and messy implementation) but every other piece of traffic was mowed down before getting a chance to arrive at my network card.